# Prove or disprove that if every proper subgroup $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Prove or disprove that if every proper subgroup $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic.

If I used group $U(8)$ as an example to disprove the statement, does it work? I just say that every subgroup of $U(8)$ is of order $2$ and that they are cyclic: $\langle 3\rangle = \{1,3\}, \langle 5\rangle = \{1,5\}$ and $\langle 7\rangle= \{1,7\}.$

I saw an other post saying that $C_2 \times C_2$ disproved the statement, but I want to check if the way I did it works.

Comment: Yes, it’s true. And $U(8)$ is isomorphic to $C2\times C2$, so it is the “same’ example.

Comment: $S_3$ is an non-abelian counterexample.

Comment: If there is any non-cyclic finite group, then such a group of minimum order must be a counterexample.

Comment: @ahulpke U(8) is isomorphic to C2 x C2 because they share the same order?

Comment: @TheMathAI. No, the order alone is not sufficient. It is being abelian of order 4 and having the same element orders.

Comment: If every subgroup is cyclic then the group may not be abelian so it is not cyclic $Q_8$ and $S_3$ are the examples.

Answer (score 1):

In your explanation, we can also say that if a cyclic group of order $n$ must have exactly $\phi(n)$ of order $n$, So in your case, if group $G$ is cyclic of order $4$ then it must have $\phi(4)=2$ elements of order $4$ which are not there, So your example will also work, This explanation by the definition of a cyclic group.
For more reading, you can see in 'cyclic group' in "Contemporary Abstract Algebra".

**Note:** Even if every subgroup is cyclic then the group may not be abelian so it is not cyclic, $Q_8$ and $S_3$ are the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very quick (dis)proof: There exist non-cyclic finite groups.

(If the statement held then every finite group would be cyclic, because if $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ then all proper subgroups are of smaller order, hence cyclic by induction. If the statement held then $G$ would be cyclic, and hence all finite groups would be cyclic.)